# 'jupyter notebook' command not working on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I recently installed Jupyter Notebook on my Linux machine (which has Python 3.6 installed) according to their [instructions](http://jupyter.org/install):

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

However, when I run

```
jupyter notebook
```

I get the following error:

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I run:

```
cd /usr/bin
ls -l | grep jupyter
```

The results are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         397 Feb 20 00:29 jupyter
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         413 Feb 20 00:29 jupyter-migrate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         423 Feb 20 00:29 jupyter-troubleshoot
```

There doesn't seem to be a 'notebook' script in there.

`python3 -m pip list` includes `notebook 5.5.0` in its output.

Other answers suggest installing Anaconda, but I'd like to avoid that for now. I'm just curious why it isn't working, since the installation instructions were very brief and clear.

**I'm more looking to understand the problem, rather than for a quick fix. Thanks!**

Edit: `jupyter notebook` now seems to work properly after another restart + reinstall. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `notebook` package - can you run `python3 -m pip list` and add the output to the question?

Comment: Hmm, the output includes `notebook 5.5.0`. Question edited

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something went wrong with your installation.

If you want to use pip please try:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

If this doesn't work please install Jupyter using this command:

```
sudo apt install jupyter-notebook
```

Comment: I believe your first suggestion is what fixed it, though I am not 100% sure. I did not use the `--force-reinstall` option.

Comment: Do not use pip to upgrade pip on ubuntu, it could break pip. The part that made it work was `sudo apt install jupyter-notebook`.

Comment: Hi @ThisGuyCantEven...
What do you mean by saying do not use pip to upgrade pip on Ubuntu?
I never suggested that...

Comment: I used your answer in an attempt to solve this problem and it broke pip on my machine, this is a known issue and the folks at pip are working on it. Lots of Info [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599). If you run `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and and it breaks your pip, the solution is to downgrade back to pip 9.0.1

Comment: `python3 -m pip uninstall pip`
`sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3-pip`

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven
Sorry but I still do not understand where I've suggested upgrade pip in my answer. It is not there...

Comment: The only thing I've suggested to reinstall is jupyter: pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven Please provide input in order not to confuse future readers

Answer (score 2):

can you test if it will run with

`python -m notebook`

also i search why it is happened

Comment: Additional deets on '-m' option by typing "man python" into terminal.

Answer (score 0):

## Assuming you are interested in python 3 on Ubuntu (Tested on Kali Linux too)

1. installing pip and python-dev will help you to download Python-specific packages.

> > $ sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
> >
> > $ sudo apt-get -y install python3-dev

2. upgraded pip to the latest version.

> > $ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip

3. install Jupyter

> > $ sudo -H pip3 install jupyter OR sudo apt install jupyter-notebook

4. Create a config file for Jupyter

> > $ jupyter notebook --generate-config

5. Add two lines below to the newly created config file that will make you able to use your Jupyter notebook from a browser window (you can use nano or vim to add manually.

> > $ echo "c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'" >> /home/[your_username]/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
> >
> > $ echo "c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True" >> /home/[your_username]/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

6. Test Jupyter by typing

> > $ jupyter notebook --browser

This command will start to run the Jupyter application on your server or local machine.

While it’s running in Terminal, just open a browser and type in localhost or server ip followed by :8888 e.g

> > if you are running it on a server, use server's ip like so 192.x.x.x:8888 on your browser (any machine anywhere)
> >
> > if you are running it on a PC then type localhost:8888 on your browser (limited within your PC running jupyter)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You might try by typing in command window (as showing in image)

```
py -m notebook
```

[image]

Hope it works.